# C++ LibcURL IMAP fetch what is the variable holding the subject line?

Tags: c++, email, curl, imap, libcurl

Code is https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/imap-fetch.html

In that example what would be variable holding the Subject line be.  It prints it out in the console but I would like to be able to compare the content of the subject. For instance if I wanted to:

```
    If (subject == "sample text") {
Do things;
}
```

Comment: That example downloads the email and dumps it to the console. There is no variable for you to examine. To do what you want, you will have to use [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) to save the downloaded email to a buffer of your choosing (see [this example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html)), and then you will have to parse the email data once `curl_easy_perform()` has finished downloading it. cURL will not parse the email for you, but there are plenty of 3rd party email parsers you can use, or you can just parse it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me although having an entire extra function inside of the main.cpp file seems a bit bulky.  Wish curl had an function to store to a variable integrated into it so that it would only require one line of code.

If you want the rep copy and paste to an answer.

Comment: "*Wish curl had an function to store to a variable integrated into it so that it would only require one line of code.*" - welcome to programming. You will rarely encounter neat one-line solutions to complex tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a URL that retrieves only the subject, if that's what you want.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                 "imap://imap.example.com/INBOX/;UID=1;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(Subject)");
```

Some of the [existing questions about imap+libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imap+libcurl) may also interest you. (That "tagged/tag+tag" format of that link is a great way to find things on SO, BTW.)